# UI TableView Controller

Tags: swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource
 {

code

}
```

I removed these two classes/interfaces **UITableViewDataSource,** **UITableViewDelegate** when using TableViewController. still its working fine.
WHY?

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController
{

 code

}
```

so why we use these classes?

Comment: are you using static tableView cells or dynamic cells using prototype?

Comment: They are not classes, they are protocols

Answer (score 0):

It's Still working because `UITableViewController` already implements the delegates `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource` :)

Comment: So why we use these classes, what is the purpose of using it?

Comment: You can use UITableView independently.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is a viewcontroller which already contain a `UITableView` inside it, But whenever u need a custom `UIViewController` which have a `UITableView` & many more UI components, u need `UITableViewDatasource` & `UItableViewDelegate` independently.

Comment: The `HomeViewController` is inheriting from `UIViewController` not `UITableViewController`

Comment: are you setting your table view's datasource & delegate ? inside the code implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController` is fundamentally constructed to manage a table view. Hence it implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` by default.
Your `HomeViewController` is simply a subclass of `UIViewController`. Therefore it doesn't have an inherent responsibility of managing a table view. So it's not a problem, if it doesn't conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: The `HomeViewController` is inheriting from `UIViewController` not `UITableViewController`

Comment: That's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Tableview in a UIView you have to follow certain rules like telling the table how many rows to display. Adding `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` after the name of the class is telling xCode that you want to follow the rules for a table so xCode can make sure you follow all the required rules.

In your case, you have followed all the rules: you linked the datasource and the delegate to your HomeViewController ad implemented the required methods so it's working you are just doing it without informing the IDE and the compiler.

In other words it works because you are doing it right but you don't have adequate checks in place to make sure you are doing it right.